# Process.Start doesn´t work, or do nothing

Tags: c#, command-line, process.start

I have made an .exe application compiling using the following command, this generate a .exe file

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe", @"/t: exe" + item");
```

the `item` corresponds to the path where the file .cs was ...
On the other hand, I am trying to execute that file with this code:

`Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/k C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Test1\HelloWorld.exe");`

And this code doesn`t work...

My goal is to show the cmd to view "Hello World"... Thanks!

Comment: Instead of launching cmd.exe, can you launch your exe directly? I assume it does exist and can be started by hand?

Comment: Yes, the .exe exits and I can start bt hand!